# Consume service bus message after x time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, azureservicebus, messagebroker

I'm doing a project to study more of brokers and i'm using .NET 6.0 and Service bus to do this.

My question is: I need to publish a message and consume the same message only after a few time (i put the time in an enviroment variable to control it), how can i do this?

I know, it's not a good practice doing this, "empty queue is a healthy queue", but it's a personal project.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want the queue to delay the message for a fixed amount of time?

Comment: You can indeed schedule messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages

Comment: See the sample for scheduling a message [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample01_SendReceive.md#schedule-a-message)

Comment: @Filipe Eduardo Did the above links resolve your answer

Comment: Hi guys, it's exactly what i want, thanks!

Comment: @Filipe Eduardo please post your answer for SO Community benefits .So I helps Others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consume service bus message after x time

I do agree with discussion in comments , You can also use blow code to do the same:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

class Program
{
    const string rithcon = "Endpoint=sb://siln-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=WFsJyG1O3qA=";
    const string rithqueuename = "rithwik";
    static IQueueClient rithqc; 

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        rithqc = new QueueClient(rithcon, rithqueuename);
        await RithSendMessageAsync("Hello Rithwik Bojja!");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        await RithReceiveMessageAsync();
    }

    static async Task RithSendMessageAsync(string rithmessageBody)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rithmessageBody))
            {
                ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)
            };
            await rithqc.SendAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Hey Man the Message sent: {rithmessageBody}");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    static async Task RithReceiveMessageAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            rithqc.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            });

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }
        finally
        {
            await rithqc.CloseAsync();
        }
    }

    static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message rithmessage, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rithmessage.Body)}");

        await rithqc.CompleteAsync(rithmessage.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
    static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In my code i have kept 1 min time to consume the message.

**`Output:`**

After sending message:

[image]

[image]

After receiving and consuming the message:

[image]

[image]